# Icon on Silverlight web page

Tags: html, silverlight-3.0, favicon

I was wondering how to add our own custom icon to the web page for our Silverlight application? I know how to set the text (using the Title property for the Page), but the icon eludes me.

For example, see the below image. The most left tab has the G for Google, and the most right one has the CNN icon. How can I get my own there?

[alt text http://www.umail.ucsb.edu/~mguidry/firefox/tab.jpg](http://www.umail.ucsb.edu/~mguidry/firefox/tab.jpg)

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm...

Putting the favicon in the root works in Firefox and Google Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer. Any thoughts on what might cause this?

EDIT: Found the error. IE accepts only .ico files. So by putting an icon called favicon.ico in my root folder, and adding these lines to my .aspx page, everything works:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 4):

This is actually just a standard web convention and works independently of Silverlight.

Begin by generating your icon file (you can use a [site like this](http://www.favicon.cc) as a shortcut) and upload the icon file to your site root- giving it the name **favicon.ico**

Refresh the page (might need to  + F5 to clear cache) and your icon should appear as desired.

Comment: I tried adding the favicon to different locations, but no luck so far. Which location actually IS my site root? I'm running the site locally at the moment.

Comment: @frances the folder which corresponds to / on your site. For example, if I go to `http://localhost/hello.aspx`, the folder `hello.aspx` is in would be the root.

Comment: @Rex M: Tried that, didn't work. Maybe its different for Silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful
http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Also, if you need to create a favicon it needs to be in the ".ico" format. Using photoshop you can create an icon, but you need a plugin to export to the favicon.ico format.

http://www.photoshopsupport.com/tutorials/jennifer/favicon.html

And you site root is where your very first homepage resides for example index.html or index.asp, or index.php.

On most web hosting plans there is a folder called "public_html" if you see a folder like this that is most likely your "root" folder.